# How to redirect a file pwd that's in another file to a diff -q command?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm doing a shell-script, and I have a file named pathFileOriginal. This file contains the pwd to another file, I'm calling it fileOriginal.

And I want to compare the ls -lR of this fileOriginal with another file called fileProtected.

I wanted to extract the path that's inside pathFileOriginal, to reach fileOriginal, do ls -LR of fileOriginal, and finally compare it with fileProtected. 
And then I wanted to print their differences.

So I tried doing

```
echo "$(cat pathfileOriginal)" | ls -lR >> $HOME/fileNow
diff -q $fileNow $fileProtected
```

However after running the script in the terminal I got,

```
cat: pathfileOriginal: No such file or directory
diff: missing operand after '-q'
diff: Try 'diff --help' for more information
```

.

Comment: `pathfileOriginal: No such file or directory` - well, where is pathfileOriginal? | `echo "$(cat pathfileOriginal)"` is conceptually wrong. | `| ls -lR` - `ls` does not read anything from standard input

Comment: [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is relevant.

Comment: ...anyhow, it sounds like what's actually desired is `diff -q <(ls -lR "$(<pathFileOriginal)") fileProtected`. Except of course the error message says that there's no `pathFileOriginal` on disk, even though the OP says that it's a filename, not a variable name... which is to say, this is just a mess, and needs a [mcve] -- with emphasis on the "complete" (which includes things like including code to create your input files in the question) and "verifiable" (meaning that the code you provide needs to be runnable/testable by people here without fixes/changes/setup that isn't included).

Comment: Note that `pwd` means "print working directory", so there's no such thing as "the pwd to another file".

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need something like this

```
diff -q <(ls -lR "$(cat path/to/pathFileOriginal)") <(ls -lR path/to/fileProtected)
```

If I misunderstood and you actually don't want to compare against the output of `ls -lR` run on fileProtected :

```
diff -q <(ls -lR "$(cat path/to/pathFileOriginal)") path/to/fileProtected
```

Comment: However when i do, `ls -lR "$(cat path/to/pathFileOriginal)"`,  this command doesn't work how I expected, instead of listing the the files from the cat of pathFileOriginal, it lists the files from the directory where I have the script